# Insert text in other apps automatically - swift4

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I have a simple application, which can send user `UNNotification` periodically. I want to insert/paste some strings into the application which is behind of the notification.

**For example**, if the user is on the **Note application** on his iPhone, when he received my notification, I want to insert some texts in the opened Note.

Is this possible?

here is my code for sending the notification:

```
    let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    notification.subtitle = Message
    notification.body = "Expand this notification for more options"
    notification.categoryIdentifier = "Event"
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Event",
                                          actions: [],
                                          intentIdentifiers: [],
                                          options: [])
    let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: GenerateFireDate(), repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Event",
                                        content: notification,
                                        trigger: notificationTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

**Update**

I know I have a straightforward solution, which is to open the notification and `Copy` text in the `UIPasteboard`. But I am looking for an alternative way, which is more convenient rather than open-and-copy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Consider that situation where any application would be able to paste in text using anywhere – it would not exactly make of a good experience.

A way around it would be that you instruct the user to tap the notification to open your app. Then you could add text to clipboard. Read more about `UIPasteboard` [in its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard).

Comment: I am using this solution now indeed, but I am looking for another solution that may be more convenient for the user

Comment: This is only possible when there has to be multiple user interactions.
ie : Notification pops up, user **touches** notification, your application opens, 
Alert pops up, inquiring user to again go the required app(notepad), with the  string or information along, user **selects** ok, notepad opens.